# How to create clickable search results in live search bar

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, typeahead.js

My live search bar displays search results in the following manner :

[{"item_name":"johnnie-walker-odyssey","href":"profile.php?item_name=johnnie-walker-odyssey"},{"item_name":"jack daniels tennessee-fire","href":"profile.php?item_name=jack daniels tennessee-fire"}.

I intend to display the results as links so when a user clicks on his desired result, they can be redirected to another page that displays details of the result.

```
<?php   
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "charles", "shoppingcartdemo");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$term = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['term']);

if(isset($term)){
// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM shopping_items WHERE item_name LIKE '" . $term . "%'";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

//display search results links   
$array [] = array("item_name"=> $row['item_name'],"href"=>"profile.php? 
item_name=".$row['item_name']);}
echo json_encode($array)
// Close result set
mysqli_free_result($result);
} else{
echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
}
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}


}


// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: When you clicked to create this post the button said "Ask Question". But you haven't really asked one, or presented us with any kind of concrete problem. "how to" is too vague - there could be many ways you might want to do it, and many small details to decide upon. Here at StackOverflow we will help you fix bugs, but we will not just do your research or coding for you completely. What research have you done? What code have you tried? What problem are you facing? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further guidance on how to ask a useful question.

Comment: This is really going to have nothing to do with the code you've posted and everything to do with your Javascript (and HTML) code.

Comment: You need to fetch data inside an anchor tag. You can serach web for tutorials like this: https://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/dynamic-menu-in-php/ Other than that we can't help much without seeing any code to fix here.

Comment: What i really mean to ask is how do i correct my code so it displays results of the search bar as links because currently my code displays the php code insted of links as shown in the question part. I'm willing to use another technique if the one i've used cannot acomplish the task. Thanks in advance